# duplicate comments in php page

Tags: php, mysql

I have code for comments in php page

but when I am doing refresh page after posting comment then same comment is getting posted
again and stored in database also.
please help me

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
mysql_select_db("comments");

$name=$_POST['name'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$submit=$_POST['submit'];

$dbLink = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "a12345");
mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8", $dbLink);
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8", $dbLink);

if($submit)
{
    if($name&&$comment)
    {
        $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment') ");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "please fill out all fields";
    }}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Comment box</title>
</head>

<body>
<center>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr><td>Name: <br><input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">Comment: </td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="5"><textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>

    <?php
    $dbLink = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "a12345");
    mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $dbLink);
    mb_language('uni');
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

    $getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC");

    while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
    {
        $id=$rows['id'];
        $name=$rows['name'];
        $comment=$rows['comment'];
        echo $name . '<br/>' . '<br/>' . $comment . '<br/>' . '<br/>' . '<hr size="1"/>'
        ;
    }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using:

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? 
$_POST['name'] : '';
$comment = isset($_POST['comment']) ? 
$_POST['comment'] : '';
$submit = isset($_POST['submit']) ? 
$_POST['submit'] : '';
```

but without Benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After submitting a comment, if you refresh the page, you are submitting the same comment over. That is why they are duplicated.

The best way to deal with this is to **either** put your INSERT query in another php file and then redirect to the comments page after submission **or** if you want to keep it in the same file, then redirect to the same page using `header` function after you insert the comment to the database.

A simple way to fix:

```
if($submit)
{
 if($name && $comment)
 {
   $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment') ");
   header( 'Location: http://the url of your page') ;
  }
  else
  { 
    echo "please fill out all fields";
  }

}
```

Please note that your code is not secure.

Comment: This is not the solution . It is an alternative. If one needs to save on the same page why create separate file.

Comment: It is a solution. I suggested either using separate php files or refresh to the same page without passing the POST inforamtion. When you are giving negative points make sure you understand the question and the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `unset()` after the `$insert` query

```
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment') ");
unset($_POST['submit']);  
header("location:yourfile.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid this

```
$submit = isset($_POST['submit']) ? 
$_POST['submit'] : '';
```

and use

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//here the insertion query..
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After doing your work with post you can unset `POST` with `unset($_POST)`.
This will empty the post and refresh will not bring values again.

Comment: Not going to work. Once the page is refreshed, it will set the value of '$_POST' to what was submitted, and inserted into db.